# Draw on custom view with zoom not working properly

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, pinchzoom, android-bitmap

When drawing on view without zoom it works fine. See the screenshot[image]

But when zooming and then drawing on view It is slightly up or down. See the screenshot

[image: With Zoom]

Here is my code for Custom View http://www.paste.org/78026 and for zoom  http://www.paste.org/78027 and my xml http://www.paste.org/78028

Please can you tell me where I am wrong

Comment: your above issue resolve?

Comment: @Jiks Yes It was resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of searching I found how to get relative X,Y when View is zoomed. It may be helpful to someone

```
// Get the values of the matrix
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);

// values[2] and values[5] are the x,y coordinates of the top left     corner of the drawable image, regardless of the zoom factor.
// values[0] and values[4] are the zoom factors for the image's width and height respectively. If you zoom at the same factor, these should both be the same value.

// event is the touch event for MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
float relativeX = (event.getX() - values[2]) / values[0];
float relativeY = (event.getY() - values[5]) / values[4];
```

Comment: Hello ! Could you explain more about matrix in this line matrix.getValues(values); ? What is it ?